# Weird chmod parameter - "!$"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

I found on an article a line that was saying: Now execute -> `sudo chmod 700 !$`

What does `!$` in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `chmod` parameter. See the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> `!!:$` designates the last argument of the preceding command. This may be shortened to !$

So just look at the last command to figure out what you'd `chmod`.